# WordPress+HTML -> Moodle

Tags: wordpress, html, moodle

One has a site with a lot of (***a lot of a lot of***) pages in HTML. The pages are managed through WordPress and includ motions, different fonts, videos, images, etc., ie, are elaborated pages.

Because of the Moodle is more usable, it is convenient to migrate for Moodle for continuing posting pages. However, is not good (1) Have two domains (the initial site and the moodle) nor (2) Make a PDF or other repository of the initial pages, as it would lose interactivity etc.

So, there is a manner to migrate HTML pages in automatically for Moodle (I mean, not one to one) with the minimun lose?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Moodle is not really designed to be a general CMS. It's meant for creating online learning courses. If this does not describe your content, then you probably should not use Moodle. If that _is_ your content, you have a long road ahead because I could not find anything appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, thank you so much for attention. Moodle would be nice for this purpose in fact, but it is not mandatory to be Moodle. Do you know any system+ language that is simpler and more current than WordPress + HTML and there may be this transport of pages? Thank you very much.